# "Broken" while loop in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class ValidatePercent {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean val = false;
    int pc;
    while (!val)
    {
        System.out.print("please input a percentage");
        pc=k.nextInt();
        if (pc>=0 && pc<=100){
             val = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error at line 6 "illegal start of type // cannot find symbol // symbol: class val // location: class ValidatePercent //  expected"
What does it mean? Why doesn't it work?
I have tried changing it to loop while pc is a value and then it doesn't recognise that either.

Comment: You need to put your code in a method, presumably the main method, ie: `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put these inside a `method` or a `block`.

Simply use `main()`

```
public class ValidatePercent {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
 boolean val = false;
 int pc;
 while (!val)
    {
        System.out.print("please input a percentage");
        pc=k.nextInt();
        if (pc>=0 && pc<=100){
            val = true;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

You can't use `while`, `System.out.print()` and `if` outside a `method` or a `block`

Comment: @ChrisMartin not now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into a method, like main. Main method is the one from which Java starts execution.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ValidatePercent {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean val = false;
    int pc;
    while (!val)
    {
        System.out.print("please input a percentage");
        pc=k.nextInt();
        if (pc>=0 && pc<=100){
             val = true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```